# shell getopt with help argument

Tags: shell, getopts

I'm preparing a script with `getopt`. I would like to add the help section. So if they use `--help` or `-h` it should execute the function (just print the instructions) and return it.

#### Sample code:

```bsh
log_type='unset'
state='unset'
date='unset'
help='unset'


mode="$1"
usage()
{
  echo "Usage: LogRotator [ -t | --log_type  - Allowed values: [access error] ] 
                          [ -s | --state - Allowed values: [archive or backup] ]
                          [ -d | --date 1-10-2020] 
                          [ -h | --help]

        Modes:
            1) list - list the files
            2) restore  - restore the files"
  exit 2
}


ARGUMENT_LIST=(
    "log-type"
    "state"
    "date"
)



# read arguments
opts=$(getopt \
    --longoptions "$(printf "%s:," "${ARGUMENT_LIST[@]}")",help \
    --name "$(basename "$0")" \
    --options "" \
    -- "$@"
)

VALID_ARGUMENTS=$?
if [ "$VALID_ARGUMENTS" != "0" ]; then
  usage
fi

eval set --$opts

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -t | --log-type)
            log_type=$2
            shift 2
            ;;

        -s | --state)
            state=$2
            shift 2
            ;;

        -d | --date)
        date=$2
        shift 2
        ;;

        -h | --help)
        help=1
        shift 
        ;;
        *)
        break
        ;;
    esac
done

if [[ "$help" == 1 ]]
then
    usage
fi
```

The above script is working fine, but I have added a separate section to check and call the usage function and I'm not sure it is a good practice or not.

Also, the other issue is, it's not accepting the single `-` flags (Like -h -t)

I tried to add `-o tsdh` but it didn't work.

#### Expected output:

```bsh
./script -h

Usage: LogRotator [ -t | --log_type  - Allowed values: [access error] ] 
                          [ -s | --state - Allowed values: [archive or backup] ]
                          [ -d | --date 1-10-2020] 

        Modes:
            1) list - list the files
            2) restore  - restore the files
```

Comment: Can you show how the output you needed , User Input & Output

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: "_it's not accepting the single - flags (Like -h -t)_" you haven't defined any

Comment: Where should I define? with `getopt -o` ?

Comment: See `man getopt`. The example you based your code on is partly wrong. Change `eval set --$opts` to `eval set -- "$opts"` - notice the spacing and the double quotes. On Debian systems you can find a better example at `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash`

Answer (score 5):

I'll just write it as a code review:

First, you don't specify a shebang. Without shebang, scripts are interpreted by `sh`. Your code is not in `sh` syntax. The shell whose syntax it ressembles the most would be `zsh`. Though if it weren't for the unquoted `$opts`, it would also work in ksh93 and bash. I suppose it was intended for bash as with `zsh` there would be better ways to write it.

So here:

```
#! /bin/bash -
```

Or:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

To support systems where `bash` is not in `/bin`.

> ```
> log_type='unset'
> state='unset'
> date='unset'
> help='unset'
> ```

Here, if you use a specific string as the default value, you won't be able to disambiguate the case where the user didn't specify the option from the one where they did but with a value of `unset`.

Here, I'd just do

```
unset -v log_type state date help
```

Though for boolean things, I prefer `help=false`.

> ```
> mode="$1"
> ```

Here, you're storing the first argument in `$mode`, but are not checking whether it's present or not and not removing it from the list of arguments afterwards, which means `getopt` will receive it as well!

Maybe:

```
  case $1 in
    (list | restore) mode=$1; shift;;
    (*) usage;;
  esac
```

(after the declaration of the `usage` function).

> ```
> usage()
> {
>   echo "Usage: LogRotator [ -t | --log_type  - Allowed values: [access error] ] 
>                           [ -s | --state - Allowed values: [archive or backup] ]
> ```

Note that while those `[ -t` and `[ -s` are aligned in the source code of your script, they won't be on output because of the indentation. Also, you're hardcoding the name of the script as `LogRotator` here, but using the `basename` of `$0` later on. Also, that usage message should go to stderr, so:

```
PROGNAME=${0##*/}

usage() {
  cat << EOF >&2
Usage: $PROGNAME ...
EOF
```

> ```
>                           [ -d | --date 1-10-2020]
> ```

That `1-10-2020` is probably the worst possible date format. First it's ambiguous. Most people would understand it as the 1st of October, but in parts of North America for instance, it would be understood as the 10th of January. Also, these strings don't sort chronologically the same as lexically (even after you reorder the fields as the parts are not zero-padded).

There is an international format for date. 2020-10-01 would be standard, recognised by most people and utilities and sort lexically the same as chronologically.

[...]

> ```
> ARGUMENT_LIST=(
>     "log-type"
>     "state"
>     "date"
> )
> ```

It's preferable to leave all uppercase variables for *environment* variables.

> ```
> # read arguments
> opts=$(getopt \
>     --longoptions "$(printf "%s:," "${ARGUMENT_LIST[@]}")",help \
> ```

Here, you're appending `:,` to all the elements of `$ARGUMENT_LIST`, so that's going to result in `log-type:,state:,date:,,help`.

> ```
>     --name "$(basename "$0")" \
> ```

It should be `"$(basename -- "$0"}"` or `${0##*/}` here. Here `"$PROGNAME"` which we defined earlier.

> ```
>     --options "" \
> ```

That's for the single-character options, so you need to specify them here:

```
  --options hs:d:t:
```

> ```
>     -- "$@"
> )
>
> VALID_ARGUMENTS=$?
> if [ "$VALID_ARGUMENTS" != "0" ]; then
> ```

`if` checks for the sucess of commands. That's what it does.

So just:

```
   if 
     ! opts=$(
       ...
     )
   then
     usage
   fi
```

Or just:

```
   opts=$(...) || usage
```

here.

> ```
>   usage
> fi
>
> eval set --$opts
> ```

Leaving a parameter expansion unquoted is invoking split+glob which doesn't make sense here. Also, you need to separate that `--` from the rest here. It's `set -- <contents-of-$opts>` that you want to be evaluated as shell code, so:

```
   eval "set -- $opts"
```

> ```
> while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
>     case "$1" in
>         -t | --log-type)
>             log_type=$2
> ```

You'll want to check the supplied value against the allowed set here, to warn the user if they use `-t blah -t error`. You could also warn the user that only the last specified type will be taken into account.

> ```
>             shift 2
>             ;;
>
>         -s | --state)
>             state=$2
>             shift 2
>             ;;
>
>         -d | --date)
>         date=$2
> ```

Watch indentation. Consistent indentation makes code easier to read and helps avoiding some mistakes.

> ```
>         shift 2
>         ;;
>
>         -h | --help)
>         help=1
>         shift 
>         ;;
>         *)
>         break
> ```

Should be `shift; break` here as `getopt` will have added a `--` to tell you where the options ended.

> ```
>         ;;
>     esac
> done
> ```

At this point, you may want to check whether more arguments are available and report an error if they are not expected:

```
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || usage
```

> ```
> if [[ "$help" == 1 ]]
> then
>     usage
> fi
> ```

If you had used `help=false`/`help=true`, then that would just be:

```
  if "$help"; then
    usage
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your script by adding short options in `getopt`, note that `:` after each `opt` means that an argument is required by this option :

```
#!/bin/bash
log_type='unset'
state='unset'
date='unset'
help='unset'


mode="$1"
usage()
{
  echo "Usage: LogRotator [ -t | --log_type  - Allowed values: [access error] ] 
                          [ -s | --state - Allowed values: [archive or backup] ]
                          [ -d | --date 1-10-2020] 
                          [ -h | --help]

        Modes:
            1) list - list the files
            2) restore  - restore the files"
  exit 2
}


ARGUMENT_LIST=(
    "log-type"
    "state"
    "date"
)



# read arguments
opts=$(getopt \
    -o t:s:d:h \
    --longoptions "$(printf "%s:," "${ARGUMENT_LIST[@]}")",help \
    --name "$(basename "$0")" \
    -- "$@"
)

VALID_ARGUMENTS=$?
if [ "$VALID_ARGUMENTS" != "0" ]; then
  usage
fi

eval set -- $opts

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        -t | --log-type)
            log_type=$2
            shift 2
            ;;

        -s | --state)
            state=$2
            shift 2
            ;;

        -d | --date)
        date=$2
        shift 2
        ;;

        -h | --help)
        help=1
        shift
        ;;
        *)
        break
        ;;
    esac
done

if [[ "$help" == 1 ]]
then
    usage
fi
```

Comment: Can you tell how you executed this script